# Как запустить процесс в фоне/отдельным потоком?

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Сабж.
Произвожу парсинг страницы и добавляю некие элементы парсинга в `ListView`.
Процесс занимает ~1-2 секунды.

Так вот, в этот промежуток, ~1-2секунды, все приложение никак не реагирует (виснет, пока все элементы не будут добавлены в листвью).

**Вопрос:**
как этого избежать?

Comment: @Kenpachi, не стоит дублировать теги в заголовке вопроса. А также не забывайте принимать верные ответы!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вам повезло, что процесс парсинга у вас занимает 1-2 секунды. Если бы 5 то система показала бы ANR-диалог. Вообще категорически нельзя в UI-потоке делать какие-то "длинные" вычисления (работа с БД, работа с сетью, whatever...), вообще.
Теперь по вопросу: вам поможет внедрение AsyncTask-ов. Подробнее можно почитать [здесь](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: Спасибо вам большое =) буду пробовать.

Comment: Пытаюсь сделать через AsyncTask. Но как мне получить сгенерированый ArrayList из класса  AsyncTask'a в мой основной.

Или наоборот, как в классе AsyncTask'a добавить итемы в ListView?

Answer (score 2):

Возможный вариант - это запуск службы:

```
public class CustomService extends IntentService {

    public CustomService () {
        super("CustomService");
    }

    public CustomService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO: Выполнить длительную работу
    }

}
```

и где-то в коде

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, CustomService.class);

startService(i);
```

Comment: Мне тоже нужно запустить кое-что в отдельном процессе и выбрал именно вариант с сервисом. Но по дефолту он будет в main-потоке. Как сделать, чтобы он выполнялся в отдельном потоке?

Comment: Сервис будет выполняться в главном потоке в любом случае (есть вариант в другом процессе). В сервисе точно также надо создавать Thread или SyncTask (раз уж про него в топике речь идет).

Answer (score 2):

Сам парсинг занимает столько или добавление? Или у Вас добавление идет в процессе парсинга?

Если элементов много лучше создать adapter и вычислять элементы списка когда они понядобятся. Либо вычислить массив в потоке, потом его передать через ArrayAdapter в ListView.
По поводу потоков, объявляем класс наследник Thread, перекрываем метод run(). дальше в основном потоке создаем экземпляр и запускаем start(). Пока поток не отработает можно вывести диалог please wait. В документации по андроиду есть примеры с потоками, да и в сети их полно...

Comment: Конечно можно и вручную потоками рулить. Но если требуется простое и быстрое решение то лучше воспользоваться AsyncTask-ом

Comment: Сначала все парсится. Скажем так название ссылки добавляется в ArrayList потом добавляется в ListView.

Пытаюсь сделать через AsyncTask. Но как мне получить сгенерированый ArrayList из класса  AsyncTask'a в мой основной.

Или наоборот, как в классе AsyncTask'a добавить итемы в ListView?

Comment: @vitaly_gashock AsyncTask это просто обертка, тут кому что больше нравится, Thread просто больше свободы дает, не принципиально.

@Kenpachi Можно в onPostExecute (который вызывается синхронно с главным потоком) передать полученный ArrayList.

Comment: Ну передам, а как быть дальше?

Comment: Дальше создаете adapter, который скрамливается ListView. Примеры про ListView посмотрите в SDK. данные вручную в ListView не добавляют, пользуются адаптерами.